# Do I need special tools to run speaker wire vertically from about light switch heigh to the floor? No fireblocks.

Tags: wiring, wire, speakers

I have some speakers I hope to run wires for from not much higher than switch height for my 7.1 system. I'm thinking I might be able to just drill a hole and use a coat hanger to get it started then push it down. I haven't done this work but my stud finder doesn't seem to indicate any blockage and there is a light switch panel in that area so I was thinking it might not be too bad.

The wall is a framed drywall wall against a concrete wall in a finished basement.

Do I need an expensive wire puller or will this approach work.

Comment: use gravity .... tie a weight (large nut) to a string .... cut holes in wall .... drop weight inside the top hole .... use string to pull wire

Comment: Wish I didn't give up fishing. Guess I'll try this and see what it takes to drop through the insulation.

Comment: you made no mention of insulation in your question .... the idea of dropping a weight inside the wall will most likely not work .... your original  idea with the coat hanger is better ..... completely straighten the coat hanger, then give it a slight bend .... tape up one end so that it does not dig into the back of the wall board ..... push it down at the  top hole so that the tip scrapes the back of the wall board (that way it avoids the insulation) .... when it comes out the bottom hole, tape a string to it and pull the string up .... use the string to pull the wires

Answer (score 3):

There's probably no reason that it won't work. Just feed the wire in and let gravity do its thing. Use a thin wire to capture the cable at the bottom hole.

A wire puller is nothing more than a stiff wire itself, with a hook or eye at the end. I've pulled wires many times using a length of copper building wire or whatever I have on hand.

Comment: I was mostly concerned about the resistance required to beat the insulation. Didn't want to make too big a hole as I wasn't planning on putting a box in and wanted to be able to easily patch it when I sell the house a few years from now. I like having a well laid out surround sound setup but maybe the buyers won't. Or I could be wrong and many would like nice pre run speaker wiring.